# I need advice with string.index

Tags: ruby

I'd like to get this line of ruby code working(I always get 0).

```
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ."

letter = gets
puts alphabet.index(letter).to_i
```

I'd like to get the position of the letter in the alphabet.

Comment: Fun tidbit: In `2.6` ruby introduced `Enumerable#chain` so we can convert this problem to `('A'..'Z').chain('a'..'z',' .'.enum_for(:each_char)).find_index(letter.chomp)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following,

```
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ."

letter = gets.chomp
puts alphabet.index(letter)
```

You need to chomp `\n` coming after letter entered which is the result of pressing "enter" afterwards,

```
>   letter = gets
B
 => "B\n"
```

Comment: _"whenever you provide letter as input it add extra line character"_ – nitpicking, but the newline character isn't caused by the letter, it's the result of pressing "enter" afterwards.